# How to improve performance of drawing many polygons on map?

Tags: ios, google-maps, polygon

Does anyone know how to improve the performance when drawing a lot of polygons on the map.

I have to draw about 900 polygons on Google Maps.

Here is my code to draw the polygons:

```
for (Polygon* poly in _allPolygons)
{
    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    for (CLLocation *loc in poly.points)
    {
        [path addCoordinate:loc.coordinate];
    }

    GMSPolyline *polyLine = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    polyLine.map = self.mapView;
}
```

Comment: Try to move the initialisation loop to background thread, make only UI changes on the main thread. it should make the app more responsive although the whole task will take more time to finish.

Comment: @A-Live it is not allowed to perform drawing methods on background thread.

Comment: That's why I said to do the UI part on the main thread.

Comment: The problem is not the initialisation. After drawing all the polygons the map is really laggy especially zooming.

Comment: Whats the average number of points per polygon or total number of points? If the map is laggy then you probably have too many points. Best bet might be to add points a few at a time until the map gets laggy then reduce the number of points in the polygons until it gets down below the lag threshold. Then again, the lag could also come from the number of polygons.

Comment: @Nuclearman I know that the problem is caused by too many points per polygon, unfortunately I can not reduce the number of points, because they are really essential for the app.

Comment: Then your are SOL as far as your question goes. This is a classic case of the XY Problem. You are asking about your solution to your actual problem, when you should be asking about the problem itself. What are you actually trying to do. What are you actually trying to do with the polygons/points? What do the polygons represent? Why so many polygons/points? What is keeping you from reducing the number of points? You might want to make a new question for that.

Comment: You should take a look at mapbox gl js.  They tile the vectors on the fly client-side which gives you the ability to draw tens of thousands of them.